# Group By and multiply Each Row With Two different column

Tags: mysql

```
 Quantity          Litre          BillNo
 2                 1.00           1
 3                 0.76           1
 5                 1.00           2
 5                 1.00           2
```

Expected Result

```
 Quantity          Litre          BillNo
 5                 4.28           1
 10                10.00          2
```

How to count litre
in BillNo 1

2 Quantity * 1.00 Litre = 2.00  Litre

3 Quantity * 0.76 Litre = 2.28 Litre

So Total litre Of Bill 1 is 4.28 and Quantity 2+3=5,

Same as in Bill 2, How can i get Expected Result.

Sorry if i can't explain well......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sum and group by

```
 select 
   sum(quantity) as  quantity
 , sum(litre) as litre
 , sum(quanty*litre) as Total
 , billNo 
 from my_table 
 group by biiNo
```